# Simple outer apply not working in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a domain class like below :

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public int DeptId { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Transaction 
    {
        public int TRID { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I want to get all employees from the EmployeeTable for DeptId = 100. I want to calculate Pending status for those employees whose transactions are pending.

So if employee records are found in Transactions table then just want to return a column saying whether employee has any pending transactions or not)

Query :

```
var t = (from e in _employeeRepository.GetAll() //returns IQueryable<Employee>
                                 where e.DeptId == 100
                                 from t in _transactionRepository.GetAll().Where(t => t.EmployeeId == e.EmployeeId)
                                 select new 
                                 {
                                    IsPendingTransaction = (t != null && t.Status != "Done") ? true : false,
                                 }).ToList();
```

> Error : LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
> 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Transaction] GetAll()' method, and this
> method cannot be translated into a store expression."}

Sql Query :

```
SELECT e.*
(CASE WHEN (t.EmployeeId is not null and t.Status <> 'Done')
             THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) 
             ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) 
        End) as IsPendingTransaction
FROM Employee e OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT t.*
      FROM Transactions t 
      WHERE e.EmployeeId = t.EmployeeId
     ) t
WHERE e.DeptId = 100;
```

Comment: You have 2 different querables from 2 different contexts and trying to join them. EF will never allow this. Forget about repositories and make one good query from dbcontext.

Comment: @Serge But join works fine then why doesn't it? Can you explain what is happening here just for my knowledge, please?

Answer (score 1):

Fix Transaction class

```
public class Transaction 
    {
        public int TRID { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }

        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
       
    }
```

It is not the best idea to have a separate repository  for each entity since query usually consists from several entities. It is better to make a join using dbcontext then several repository queries as you trying to do. Don't try to create a  base generic repository also. Sooner or later you will see that is is not very helpfull. So add in one of your repositories (probably EmployeeRepository) query like this

```
var employees= dbcontext.Transactions
.Where(t=> t.Employee.DeptId == 100  && t.EmployeeId==employeeId)
.Select (t=>  new  { 
EmployeeName= t.Employee.Name,
IsPendingTransaction = (t.Status != null && t.Status != "Done") ? true : false​}).ToList()
```

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me. Join works fine then why doesn't it? Can you explain what is happening in my query just for my knowledge, please?

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow Let me know if you have any problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you work within `IQueryable`, every statement inside that Linq expression must be understood by EF to be able to be translated to SQL.

Your first repository call returns an `IQueryable<Employee>` which you are trying to extend by telling it to join on some code called "_transactionRepository.GetAll()" EF doesn't know what this is, it doesn't correlate to mapped DbSets or properties on entities...

If your Transaction entity has a navigation property back to Employee (which it should) you should be able to accomplish what you want using just the TransactionRepository with something like:

```
var t = _transactionRepository.GetAll()
    .Where(t => t.Employee.DeptId == 100)
    .Select(t => new 
    { 
        IsPendingTransaction = (t != null && t.Status != "Done") ? true : false
    }).ToList();
```

Using `IQueryable<TEntity>` in a repository pattern can be quite powerful, however I don't recommend adopting a Generic repository pattern as it just serves to fragment your thinking when working with entities and their relationships with one another, allowing EF to manage the resulting SQL without you resorting to pre-emptively trying to do the joining yourself, often causing conflicts with what EF is capable of working out itself.

Edit: Ok, from your description to get a list of employees with a flag if they have a pending transaction:  That would be back at the Employee level with a query something like:

```
var employees = _employeeRepository.GetAll()
    .Where(e => e.DeptId == 100)
    .Select(e => 
    { 
        Employee = e,
        HasPendingTransaction = e.Transactions.Any(t => t.Status != "Done")
    }).ToList();
```

Or projected to a ViewModel to embed the HasPendingTransaction alongside the Employee details:

```
var employees = _employeeRepository.GetAll()
    .Where(e => e.DeptId == 100)
    .Select(e => new EmployeeDetailsViewModel
    { 
        EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId,
        Name = e.Name,
        // include other relevent details needed for the view...
        HasPendingTransaction = e.Transactions.Any(t => t.Status != "Done")
    }).ToList();
```

The advantage of projection is you can build more efficient / faster queries that reduce the amount of data sent over the wire and avoid issues like lazy load trips if you try to serialize entities to the view.

Comment: Upvoted your answer for such a nice explanation but I want to get list of employees and just a flag with employees data to indicate any pending transaction. 1 thing I don't understand is that how come it works with joins then?

Comment: No worries, I've expanded the answer to outline how something like that can be obtained through the `IQueryable` and navigation properties as well.